# Repeat df.reindex over multiple excel spreadsheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, indexing

Can anyone help me with how to reindex over multiple sheets of an excel doc? The column order needs switching, and the below works for a single sheet but not multiple sheets....

When opening the spreadsheet as follows:
`df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=''Sheet Name')`

## And defining the new column order as:

`cols = (['N', 'Ø'])`

## Then reindexing to that order

`df = df.reindex(columns=cols)`

It works, but when I selected sheet_name=None to read in all sheets i get the error:

"AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'reindex' "

I'm new to Python so cant understand why i cant run my reindex across all of df.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `sheet_name=None` the return is an OrderedDict of `{SheetName: pd.DataFrame}`. Here I created a simple two sheet .xlsx file with one row on each sheet, with different column labels.

```
d = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=None)

for sheet_name, df in d.items():
    print(sheet_name)
    print(f'{df}\n')

#Sheet1
#   foo  bar
#0   11   12
#
#Sheet2
#   baz  boo
#0    1    2
```

So if you wanted to modify them you could loop over the dictionary

```
# Add 20, but you could reindex for instance. 
for sheet_name, df in d.items():
    d[sheet_name] = df.add(20)

print(d)
#OrderedDict([('Sheet1',    
#                 foo  bar
#              0   31   32), 
#             ('Sheet2',   
#                 baz  boo
#              0   21   22)])
```

---

If the sheets all contain similar information, then you could `concat` into a single DataFrame. Here since there are no overlapping columns, it wouldn't make as much sense. The sheetnames are added as MultiIndex keys so you can always separate them back.

```
df = pd.concat(d, sort=False)
print(df)
#           foo   bar   baz   boo
#Sheet1 0  31.0  32.0   NaN   NaN
#Sheet2 0   NaN   NaN  21.0  22.0
```